# Trying to fix height of element so it highlights correctly when hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Hey so I have a bunch of tabs made up of like this:

```
<li><h6><a href="">Tab1</a></h6></li>
<li><h6><a href="">Tab2</a></h6></li>
<li><h6><a href="">Tab3</a></h6></li>
<li><h6><a href="">Tab4</a></h6></li>
<li><h6><a href="">Tab5</a></h6></li>
<li><h6><a href="">Tab6</a></h6></li>
```

There are all horizontally aligned with display: table-cell;

The problem is that some of them have text that wraps onto a second line, and the hover state when I mouse over an item isn't going to the full height of the row.

You can see the table I'm refering to on this site here: http://perennial.chkpt.com.au/invest-with-us/

Comment: Can't really help you without code here.  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.**

Comment: Share a fiddle ..

Comment: Paste the rest of your code that may be useful, like css and js

Comment: @LIJINSAMUEL its much better to use a stack snippet than a fiddle so that the code isnt lost when the fiddle is removed.

Comment: @Master Yoda Ok.. Thanks for the information.. :-)

Comment: @LIJINSAMUEL No problem, its just better to have everything in the question as often older questions will have parts of it removed over time including links to images, documentation and fiddles. Also edited my original comment as I felt it was a bit rude and that was never my intention :) sorry about that

Comment: @Master Yoda No problem, I understand what you are trying to express.. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `:hover` style on `li` instead of `a`.

Example: apply this style for the website you provided

```
li.ui-state-default.ui-corner-top:hover {
    background: red;
}
```